# Calendar Overlay - Colors 10+

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, style.css

I am trying to add 14+ different colors into the stock Calendar application on SharePoint online. I am happy to work within the CSS to do this, but I want 14 different colors, I'd like to choose these colors, and I would like them to display just as they would in a regular color-coded calendar overlay.

What I need: 14> colors that I can preset to different categories using the Calendar overlay option within the SharePoint stock Calendar.

What I don't need: I know how to overlay, and I know about the 9 basic colors. I would also be open to learning how to change these 9 preset colors, but so far I have only found help for on-premise SharePoint servers, not SharePoint Online.

Comment: Try here:  http://www.planetwilson.co.uk/sharepoint-2013-colour-calendar-v2/<br><br>I am not sure if it works online, but none of the configuration would require touching server.

Comment: This link went to a blank page unfortunately...

Comment: I can't help either, but I came across it this week.  This guy might be able to help.  He seems to do everything by code on page.  He offers consulting by the hour.  -No disclaimer needed, I'm not him and I don't know him, or have an business with him.
https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/

Comment: Does it allow you to overlay that many calendars? I've overwritten the preset colors before, but they rely on the classes labeled 1 through 9.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not allow you to have more than 10 overlays on a calendar, its hard coded that way.  You can read more about that [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8d2ef90-f893-44aa-80fb-e680f46f62ce/how-to-increase-the-calendar-overlay-limit-of-10?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) if you like.

As far as changing the colors of the calendar overlay goes; you can modify that with CSS.  The calendar overlays all have specific classes (e.g .ms-acal-color2. .ms-acal-selcolor2, .ms-acal-apanel-color2).  These go from the default color all the way up to the 9th (.ms-acal-apanel-color9).

Here's an example that will adjust the first two colors:

```
.ms-acal-color2{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #DB504A
}

.ms-acal-selcolor2{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #DB504A
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color2{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #DB504A;
}
.ms-acal-color3{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #464655
}

.ms-acal-selcolor3{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #464655
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color3{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #464655;
}
```

Be aware this will not be represented in the UI when you pick the colors, only when you have them chosen and are viewing the calendar.

> [Here is a useful link with more detail related to the CSS around changing the colors.](http://davidlozzi.com/color-code-sharepoint-calendar/)

Answer (score 0):

I would color code each category for calendar because you can have more than 10 categories, also customized different colors. Check this [link](http://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/) it works well for me :)

Hope this helps!